# Matzah Shemurah on the 8th day of Pesaḥ (in the Diaspora)

Tags: minhag, passover, mitzvah, matzah

According to [those who hold](http://dafyomi.co.il/pesachim/halachah/ps-hl-120.htm) that there is a Kiyyum Mitzvath 'Aseh DeOraitha (a fulfillment of a positive Biblical commandment) every time one eats a KeZayith (olive size's worth) of Matzah on Pesaḥ, does this also apply on the 8th day in Ḥutz LaAretz (the Diaspora), which is a DeRabanan (rabbinic mandate)?

Comment: Why would they be any different? We eat matza and maror at both seders _with brachot_, say kiddush both nights, etc. I see no reason to assume that we treat the second day of any yom tov any different than the first.

Comment: BTW SethJ why don't you use a 'Ẓ' for Ẓadi?

Comment: @DoubleAA To answer your second question first (forgive me), I never have. I have yet to reconcile my thoughts on how Hebrew _ought_ to be pronounced with my fear that the aforementioned thoughts might be incorrect. I remain 100% convinced about Ḥ and 'Ayin, and 90-99% convinced about Thav (or Thaw, but, again, my hesitation), so I use the first two even in Tefillah and the third quite frequently outside of Tefillah and transliterate them all in writing that way, but my reservations and nagging fear of being "incorrect" about others keeps me from committing on the rest of the Aleph Beith.

Comment: @DoubleAA Now your first question - If it's DeRabanan to begin with, then can I be said to be _fulfilling_ a _DeOraitha_? Kiddush and even SheHeḤiyanu are said MiDeRabanan (cf., Kiddushah Rabbah on Shabbath and Megillath Esther); also Birchoth Mitzvah are recited on Mitzvoth DeRabanan (cf. Maror first night, btw, and - um, again, Megillath Esther, among others).

Comment: Ahh I misunderstood. I though you were asking if there was a seperate derabanan fulfillment for each kezayit. What you are actually trying to ask is if there is a deorayta fulfillment on the eighth day. If that is so, then I agree it is not deoraita on day 8, but I think it would be a derabanan kiyum.

Comment: @DoubleAA, but wouldn't it be so (Kiyum DeRabanan) only if there was a specific enactment by the Rabanan? And was there?

Comment: There was a specific enactment:הזהרו במנהג אבותיכם Do exactly as they did. They ate maror for two nights, you eat maror two nights; they sat in the sukkah every day, you sit in the sukkah every day; they had matza as a kiyum every day, you have matza as a kiyum every day.

Comment: THe D'Rabanan here is "K'Ain D'Orita" so the rabbis had the halachic strength to give the D'Rabanan day all the quailities of a D'Orita day. הזהרו במנהג אבותיכם actually means that we should take the second day just as serious as the first and don't do things with the excuse that "it's only D'Rabanan"

Comment: [In Ḥul It's all D'rabanan anyway](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/sifri-dvarim/sifri-dvarim01.pdf#78)

Comment: @jnf 400 pages, really? Couldn't you be a _little_ more specific?

Comment: @SethJ, it takes you (or me, at least) to the right place. top of p. 80 (78th page).

Comment: @JNF, thanks. It did not do that on my phone or in Firefox. I appreciate the tip, though.

Comment: @JNF I see the page but what was your kavana exactly?

Comment: @Yehoshua - הציבי לך ציונים. Mitzvot are meant to be done in Israel, out of Israel it's only practice. This doesn't actually necessarily mean that all is drabanan.